# Show data when it's attribute is clicked using bootstrap collapsing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to show $request, $order_no, $site_location, $item_code, $Time when the $name is clicked. How can I do it? I want to use bootstrap collapsing but I am stuck. How can I pass the value as it's in a while loop and contains many elements. How could I identify which one is clicked, using bootstrap?

```
<div class="row">
    <tr><td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $name;?></div></td>
       <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $request;?></div></td>
       <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $order_no;?></div></td>
       <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $site_location;?></div></td>
       <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $item_code;?></div></td>
       <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $request;?></div></td>
      <td> <div class="col-md-2"><?php echo $Time;?></div></td>





      <td><div class="col-md-2"><a href=update_status.php?flag=p&ep=<?php echo $ee; ?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style='margin-right:60px'></span></a></div></td>
      <td><div class="col-md-2"><a href=update_status.php?flag=a&ep=<?php echo $ee; ?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style='margin-right:60px'></span></a></div></td>
      <td><div class="col-md-2"><a href=update_status.php?flag=r&ep=<?php echo $ee; ?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" style='margin-right:60px'></span></a></div></tr></td>


  </div>
```

Comment: Please watch your grammar and punctuation. In English sentences usually end with a dot or a question mark. If your question is hard to read you won't get any answers. I fixed that for you for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have multiple  elements (in a loop) and when you click on the td/col-md-2 with the $name you want to show the rest of the columns?

The Bootstrap collapse let you define a element and set it's target with:
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample"

See: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Your html could become something like this (haven't tried it yet):

```
<div class="row">
    <tr>
        <td><div class="col-md-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $name; ?>"> <?php echo $name;?></div></td>
        <div class="collapse" id="collapse<?php echo $name; ?>">
            <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $request;?></div></td>
            <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $order_no;?></div></td>
            <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $site_location;?></div></td>
            <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $item_code;?></div></td>
            <td><div class="col-md-2"> <?php echo $request;?></div></td>
            <td> <div class="col-md-2"><?php echo $Time;?></div></td>
            <td><div class="col-md-2"><a href=update_status.php?flag=p&ep=<?php echo $ee; ?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style='margin-right:60px'></span></a></div></td>
            <td><div class="col-md-2"><a href=update_status.php?flag=a&ep=<?php echo $ee; ?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style='margin-right:60px'></span></a></div></td>
            <td><div class="col-md-2"><a href=update_status.php?flag=r&ep=<?php echo $ee; ?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" style='margin-right:60px'></span></a></div></td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Hope I pointed you into the right direction.

Comment: yes you pointed out the correct thing but when I give id to to my second div, which I want to show up when the first div is clicked , It did'nt show any thing .

Comment: for example : 

<div id="#collapse">
...
</div>

Comment: i think the id in the target div need to be id="collapse", so remove the #. That is only used by bootstrap to retrieve the container. $('#collapse') in jQuery is a id selector. So keep the # in the data-target but remove it from the id attribute.